# Selecting and sorting on unique foreign key with Django

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a table called 'speed' which has a foreign key to a user row and an integer field called 'speed'. What I would like to do is get the top speed for unique users. For example:

If speed contained

```
id   |   speed   |   user_id   |
1    |    40     |     1       |
2    |    50     |     1       |
3    |    10     |     2       |
```

it would return id's 2 and 3. Is this possible using Django's database API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not quite what you asked, but gives you the list of user IDs and their associated max speeds:

```
from django.db.models import Max
Speed.objects.values_list('user').annotate(Max('speed'))
```

This might be more useful: a list of User objects with their max speeds:

```
User.objects.all().annotate(Max('speed__speed'))
```

**Edit after comment** Well, you don't show where the time is coming from, but assuming that it's another field on the Speed model, it's still fairly simple:

```
Speed.objects.filter(time__gte=fiveminutesago).values_list('user').annotate(Max('speed'))
```

See the documentation on [ordering of annotate and filter clauses](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses).

Comment: The only problem with this is that I also wish to time limit it as well. I have one function which does that, but I want another that gets top speeds within the last five minutes. I don't think I can do that using the method you just gave.

Comment: Almost there. The last thing I would love is to also get the id of the Speed object as well as the user name. It is now aggregating by user, but only the user value is available. Any way to do that?